# Handling a FormFile response from .Net API in Angular Front End

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, file, httpresponse

I am facing a problem with handling of a response in Front End (FE). I am sending a `file` and an object as `status` but in FE as soon as the response is coming the `file` is being converted to object and it's not downloading properly. I have been stuck at this. I tried to work with `responseType` as Blob but it's also not working.

Here are the codes:
API Code :
GetFormFile

```
private FormFile getFormFile(string FileName, string url)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            request.Headers.Add("accept", "*/*");
            var res = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            var readResponse = res.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            var stream = new MemoryStream(readResponse);
            var file = new FormFile(stream, 0, readResponse.Length, "name", FileName)
            {
                Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
                ContentType = "application/pdf"
            };
            return file ;
        }
```

API implementation :

```
 public IActionResult FileVal()
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> objDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            try
            {
                var form = Request.Form;
                var filesData = Request.Form.ToList();
                var SrNo= Request.Form["SrNo"].ToString();
                foreach (var formFile in form.Files)
                {
                    var res = filesRepo.ValidateFile(formFile, SrNo);
                    if (res.data["StatusCode"].ToString() == "Success")
                    {
                        return Ok(res);
                    }
                }
                objDictionary.Add("Response", "No Files present");
                _response.Status = 0;
                _response.Message = "Success";
                _response.Data = objDictionary;
                return Ok(_response);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _logger.Error(exception.ToString());
                objDictionary.Add("Response", exception.Message);
                _response.Status = 1;
                _response.Message = "error";
                _response.Data = objDictionary;
                return Ok(_response);
            }
        }
```

API Reponse :

```
{
    "data": {
        "Status": [
            {
                "message": "Validation Failed ",
                "result": "error",
                "filename": "VerifiedATL_File.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "StatusCode": "Success Call"
    },
    "file": {
        "contentType": "application/pdf",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": [
                "application/pdf"
            ]
        },
        "length": 251147,
        "name": "name",
        "fileName": "VerifiedATL_File.pdf"
    }
}
```

FrontEnd Code

```
this.https.post(`${this.VALIDATE_File}`, formData)
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log('Result - ', res);

      var statuses = res['data']['Status'];
      let filess = res['file'];
      const file = new File([filess], statuses[0].filename);
      console.log(typeof filess);
      this.filesArray[sub1.Dropzonecode] = file;
      this.statusArray[sub1.Dropzonecode] = statuses[0];
      // const link = document.createElement('a');
      // link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      // link.download = statuses[0].filename;
      // document.body.append(link);
      // link.click();
      // link.remove();
    });
```

I am still a newbie and learning to write clean code. But this front end code is not working as it is converting the whole object in a blob and that is not what I want.
Thanks in advance for helping me.
Please let me know If I need to provide any more details.

Regards,
Tony

I tried different types of returns from the API but all in vain. I tried converting the `responseType` in Front End to `blob` which is again not working and also discarding the `status` return values.

I want the FormFile return to be in File data type in Front End typescript. If that happens then I can handle all the other things - saving it, downloading it, showing it etc.

Comment: The API action method in ApiController must be `public`. From your code, the `getFormFile` method seems part of the code and where the `data` field/property comes from. Can you show the actual implementation of your API action? Thanks.

Comment: This is the method. I have a separate class created having `data` as `object` and `file` as `formfile` and the return from the above function is added in the `formfile` and sent as a result. That's why in the `response` there are additional data. Have added the implementation too. @YongShun

Comment: As you return the response with the file and other field, the response returned is a serialized JSON. The `file` field will show as an object instead of a blob. In your API, you can look for returning the `file` to base64 string instead of `FormFile`. And in your front-end, convert the base64 string to `File` object with `atob()`.

Comment: @YongShun No still not working